# JS looping through fetch in API

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Recently I've been working on this code, and I was so **puzzled** and frustrated why it is ordering the output **randomly**, but then later I realized that it is loading whichever channel loads fastest, then it's **index** becomes 0, whichever loads the fastest next, becomes 1, whichever loads fastest next becomes 2, etc.

```
var channels = [
    "UCIgnIPif1LQxkdbvBmGNNuA", // channel 1
    "UC_Qs0JhHoysG4LItMgGMHHQ", // channel 2
    "UC_puGdwVL1kc5VRhaZc6Arw", // channel 3
    "UCQvwHZVCrljzvaLVX33Qaaw"  // channel 4
      ];

var key = "cant share but i will tell you the output of the code"
var subCounts = [];
    function getSubs(id, key){


for(var i = 0; i < channels.length; i++){
 
         fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id='+channels[i]+'&key='+key+'')
        .then(response => {
            return response.json()
        }).then(data => {
        
            //name[i].innerHTML = 
            
    subCounts.push(data['items'][0].statistics.subscriberCount);
    

            });
    } // for loop close
}

setTimeout(function(){
 console.log(subCounts);
 // output example: 4, 5, 6, 7
 // another output: 5, 7, 6, 4
 // another output: 7, 4, 5, 6

}, 1500) // good enough for the fetch to load
```

it's just random (which ever loads first comes **first**).

**What I want it to do though:**
I want it to load based on the order of the channels. So channel 1 needs to load first, then channel 2, then channel 3, etc. Instead of which ever loads first.

Any help, suggestions, tips would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you should use promises and once it all loaded deal with the output as you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use async await,

```
var data = await fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id='+channels[i]+'&key='+key+'')
        .then(response => {
            return response.json()
        }).then(data => {
            //name[i].innerHTML = 
            });

subCounts.push(data['items'][0].statistics.subscriberCount);
```

Comment: While this would work, it would be less performant, as it will wait to make the next request until after the current request completes.  _This may be desirable_, but my hunch is that it most likely is not for this users scenario.

Comment: I am presuming the user wants to get all the data in a serialized way as they are in the array.

Comment: Right, but they could do that with `Promise.all` by making all requests together and just not processing them until they all complete.  With this approach here each request must complete before the next one even begins, essentially running them in a sequence rather than in parallel.

Comment: Naga Raj yes. I’m trying to get in the order they are at channels [chan 1(load first), Chan 2 (next), Chan 3 (next), etc.

Comment: @Ginfio - right, but is it critical to not begin even request channel two until channel one has fully loaded, and then not request channel three until channel two is fully loaded, and so on until the end?  If not, then this result would be slower than the answers leveraging `Promise.all`.  That said, if that _is_ what you want, then this answer would be the correct approach.  However, I suspect that that is _not_ a requirement for you.

Comment: For Async wait, don’t we need to use “async” somewhere, for await to work.? So do I put async before function()?

Answer (score 1):

This would be a good use for `Promise.all` [(docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Something like:

```js
Promise.all(
    channels.map(
        channel => fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id='+channel+'&key='+key+'')
    )
)
.then(Promise.all((responses) => responses.map(response => response.json()))
.then(responses => {
    // now responses is an array in order of the results that you can process as you wish
});
```

An alterantive would be to make `subCounts` be of the same length as `channels`, and place the `i`th channel result at index `i` in the `subCounts` array.

Comment: I believe this answer gives the user what they want _without_ the drawback of slowing down the whole operation by running the requests in sequence; until the OP can verify that that is the desired behavior, an answer like this that runs the requests in parallel is probably closer to the correct response.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming that it is OK for you to wait for all requests to complete before you begin handling their responses*, then [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) should allow you to accomplish your goal.  Below is your code rewritten roughly to use `Promise.all`:

```js
var channels = [
    "UCIgnIPif1LQxkdbvBmGNNuA", // channel 1
    "UC_Qs0JhHoysG4LItMgGMHHQ", // channel 2
    "UC_puGdwVL1kc5VRhaZc6Arw", // channel 3
    "UCQvwHZVCrljzvaLVX33Qaaw"  // channel 4
];

var key = "cant share but i will tell you the output of the code"
var subCounts = [];
function getSubs(id, key) {

    var requests = [];
    var currentRequest;

    for (var i = 0; i < channels.length; i++) {

        currentRequest = fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=' + channels[i] + '&key=' + key + '');
        requests.push(currentRequest);
            
    } // for loop close

    Promise.all(requests).then((responses) => {
        for (let j = 0; j < responses.length; j++) {
            const currentResponse = responses[j];
            const data = currentRequest.json();
            subCounts.push(data['items'][0].statistics.subscriberCount);
        }
    });
}

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(subCounts);
    // output example: 4, 5, 6, 7
    // another output: 5, 7, 6, 4
    // another output: 7, 4, 5, 6

}, 1500) // good enough for the fetch to load
```

Please note that I generally opted to use modern variable declarations of [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)/[`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/statements/const)-- you won't generally want to mix the older [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/statements/var) into code using `let`/`const` so it would be best to update all of it, or, less desirable, use `var` for all declarations.  Also, this isn't tested (obviously), so it will likely need some rework for your purposes.

If every millisecond counts and you needed to process them in order but as soon as they came in, this would need to be written differently.  If you reply as such I can try to put together a POC.